# Ideal Spring Session Timeout Configuration

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, session, spring-security, spring-session

You can either set the session timeout (say 60 minutes) for all sessions in web.xml:

```
<session-config>
  <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

or on a per-session basis using

```
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(60*60);
```

the latter you might want to do in a authorizationSuccessHandler.

```
<form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"/>
```

My questions:

1. Are the two approaches mentioned above same ?
2. If not, how to set inactive timeout as described in second approach
   via Spring Configuration XML?
3. What is the ideal approach to set set session timeout in spring
   framework?

Comment: Please clarify whether you're using [Spring Session](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/) as indicated by title of your question and `spring-session` tag? Spring Session has its own support for configuring session related aspects which you don't seem to be using.

Answer (score 1):

> Are the two approaches mentioned above same ?

Yes, only difference is in former case session timeout is set by servlet container e.g tomcat and in later case its done by Spring.

> If not, how to set inactive timeout as described in second approach
>   via Spring Configuration XML?

You have to write custom filter to set session timeout, as far as my knowledge goes there nothing where you can set session time out in Spring XML

> What is the ideal approach to set set session timeout in spring
>   framework?

Let the session timeout handle by container like one you define in web.xml, if you are changing session time a lot in running app, then you can consider Spring managed session timeout by using interceptor.